# Exercise 30 from Chapter 4, Real Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H = L_2([-\pi;\pi])$ with $[-\pi;\pi]$ identified as the unit circle. Fix a bounded
sequence $\{\lambda_n \}_{n=- \infty}^{n=\infty}$ of complex numbers, and define an operator $Tf$ given by $ Tf(x)$ ~ $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \lambda_n a_n e^{\iota nx} $ whenever         $f$ ~ $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{\iota nx}$. Such an operator is called a Fourier multiplier operator, and the sequence $\lambda_n$ is called the multiplier sequence.

(a) Show that $T$ is a bounded operator on $H$ and $\|T\| = \sup|\lambda_n|$.

(b) Verify that $T$ commutes with translations, that is, if we define $\tau_h(x) =
f(x - h)$ then $T(\tau_h) = \tau_h (T)$ for every $h \in \mathbb{R}$

(c) Conversely, prove that if $T$ is any bounded operator on $H$ that commutes
with translations, then $T$ is a Fourier multiplier operator. [Hint: Consider
$T(e^{inx})$.]

I am looking for hints for Part (c).

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(e^{inx})\sim \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}b_ke^{ikx}$. 
Then for $h\in\mathbb{R}$, by the commutation of $T$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
T(e^{in(x+h)})\sim \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}b_ke^{ikh}e^{ikx}
\end{eqnarray}
On the other hand, $T(e^{in(x+h)})=e^{inh}T(e^{inx})$. So $b_ke^{ikh}\equiv b_ke^{inh}$. 
Therefore $b_k=0$ whenever $k\neq n$.